# Merging two tables with one column difference while keeping new values in the correct column

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Im trying to merge two tables with all the same colums but one:
table 1:

```
Product Name product_Model 2022-04-19  
p1           m1            20$  
p2           m2            5$
```

table 2:

```
Product Name product_Model 2022-04-20  
p1           m1            20$  
p2           m2            10$  
p3           m3            100$
```

I wish to combine them so the final output will look like this:

```
Product Name product_Model 2022-04-19 2022-04-20    
p1           m1            20$        20$  
p2           m2            5$         10$  
p3           m3            null       100$
```

Im using this code(after removing the model column):

```
table1.merge(table2, on='Product Name', how="outer")
```

This is the result:

```
Product Name product_Model 2022-04-19 2022-04-20  
p1           m1            20$        20$  
p2           m2            5$         10$  
p3           m3            100$
```

*notice how the 100$ moved to the '*-19* column...
edit: im reading from and writing to a .csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass more than one value in `on`. So you'd have:

```
left = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Name": ["P1", "P2", "P4"],
        "Model": ["M1", "M2", "M4"],
        "2022-04-19": ["20", "5", "8"]
    }
)
right = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Name": ["P1", "P2", "P3"],
        "Model": ["M1", "M2", "M3"],
        "2022-04-20": ["20", "5", "100"]
    }
)
```

```
result = pd.merge(left, right, on=["Name", "Model"], how="outer")
result = result.fillna('null')
```

| Name | Model | 2022-04-19 | 2022-04-20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | M1 | 20 | 20 |
| P2 | M2 | 5 | 10 |
| P4 | M4 | 8 | null |
| P3 | M3 | null | 100 |

Comment: Hey George, i tried it and it didnt work.
saved me from deleting the other columns by using the "on" better but im still getting the values ander the dates pushed to the left.

Comment: I must add that im reading and writing to a .csv file.
I copied your code and in your example it works just fine

Comment: Im guessing you're using `pd.read_csv` and `pd.to_csv` so check your original input dataframes to see whether they have any issue with missing values. Maybe it has to do with how you represent missing data (see parameter `na_rep` of `pd.to_csv`). For example maybe P3 2019 value isn't represented as empty and is filled with 100$.